# compilation error regarding unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Tags: java

```
  //  Fahrenheit (°F)
```

I have the above code commented out in my java code, but I get the "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8". How do I fix this?

Comment: why do you want to use this kind of character in your actual code piece?

Comment: where you are actually putting this code, can we see the code above it and below it ?

Comment: It's just a java comment inside your method, nothing fancy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding in your javac command line using the -encoding flag

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 myclass.java
```

You can also look into making UTF-8 your system default encoding so you don't have to specify it.

Comment: how should I set it as a system level setting

Comment: It depends on your OS.  If you're running Linux you can set it in your locale to use UTF-8 as the system default.  If you're running Windows you can check in the Regional and Language options, but I don't think there's a way to make it your system default. :/  I think you'll have to wind up setting a JAVA specific environment variable.  I don't remember what it is off of the top of my head, but Google says it's LANG

Comment: I am getting this error for UTF-8 only, which is what is confusing me. >> unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Comment: Is the file saved as UTF-8?  Or as ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I followed this link (http://jvliet.blogspot.com/2006/12/setting-default-text-file-encoding-in.html) and the error went away. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Having this same compiler error with a ton of java files in the ISO-8859-1. Opening one by one is impracticable. So, here's a quick fix ([using recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/manual/Tutorial.html#Tutorial)):

```
find -name '*.java' -exec recode Latin-1..UTF-8 {} \;
```